# How to create a Django custom Field to store MYSQL DATETIME(6) and enable fractional seconds (milliseconds and or microseconds) in Django/MySQL?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-orm, django-database

MySQL 5.6.4 and up expands fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Django 1.5 and up supports fractional seconds as imputformat: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats

But the DATETIME(6) field isn't implemented in Django yet. 
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19716

I decided to write a custom DateTimeFractionField. It's the standard DateTimeField with the DATETIME([1-6]) db_type. 'precicion' is to set milliseconds, microseconds or any other fraction precicion.

```
class DateTimeFractionField(models.DateTimeField):
    description = "Datetimefield with fraction second."

    def __init__(self, precision, *args, **kwargs):
        self.precision = precision
        super(DateTimeFractionField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'DATETIME(%s)' % self.precision


class MyModel(models.Model):
    dt_micros  = DateTimeFractionField(6)
    dt_millis = DateTimeFractionField(3)
    dt = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" %(self.dt_micros, self.dt_millis)
```

The mysql backend is responsible for replacing milliseconds with 0. The Django documentation suggests to write my own backend. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#engine

I hacked:

```
$ cd /path/to/site-packages/django/db/backends/
$ cp -r mysql mysql564
```

And modified mysql564/base.py:

Line 42:45

```
from django.db.backends.mysql564.client import DatabaseClient
from django.db.backends.mysql564.creation import DatabaseCreation
from django.db.backends.mysql564.introspection import DatabaseIntrospection
from django.db.backends.mysql564.validation import DatabaseValidation
```

Line 167

```
supports_microsecond_precision = True
```

Line 214

```
compiler_module = "django.db.backends.mysql564.compiler"
```

Line 357

```
return six.text_type(value) #value.replace(microsecond=0)
```

Line 368

```
return six.text_type(value) #value.replace(microsecond=0)
```

Line 373

```
return [first, second] #return [first.replace(microsecond=0), second.replace(microsecond=0)]
```

Then i activated my new backend in settings.py:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql564',
```

When I add and save my model in the admin, the values get saved to de db! :)

[image: Sequel Pro]

But they are not returned (None - None and empty form fields). :(

[image: Django admin]

What am I missing here?

1. Why are DateTimeFractionField values not returned?
2. Is there a better (simpler) way to implement a datetimefield that support fractions?

I know there are other db's supporting fractions. But I like to use MySQL and get the ticket a little closer to fixed.

UPDATE:

It's not (only) the form, getting a datetime object from de db fails.

```
In [1]: from spacetime.models import MyModel

In [2]: from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

In [3]: get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1).dt
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 25, 0, 22, 23)

In [4]: get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1).dt_millis

In [5]: get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1).dt_millis.__class__
Out[5]: NoneType #This should be datetime.datetime
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it's kind of confusing to see what you are actually asking/ trying to do.

Comment: I try to create a DateTimeField that supports fractional seconds. My custom DateTimeField is DateTimeFractionField. It successfully saves datetime objects with fractions to the db but getting values from db to Django doesn't work. The general goal is to get a working DateTimeFractionField field. The question at the moment: Why are DateTimeFractionField values not returned?

Comment: Django doesn't support it out of the box, as I understand, because SQL doesn't really have specification for it. You could use a CharField, or write your own field that uses database-specific code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. [This ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19716) shows what can be done. A CharField isn't really an option. It isn't possible to query char fields like datetime fields. My question supplies a custom field and a custom db backend to handle microseconds (it should work). I guess things go wrong at the db interface (MySQLdb).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this succesfully, but my approach is quite different: 
I split the info in a DateTimeField (UTC) and a IntegerField (microseconds = uS):

```
from datetime                   import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

class MyModel (models.Model):
    # My model stuff and other fields here
    _UTC = models.DateTimeField ()
    _uS  = models.IntegerField()
```

And then I set a property in the class to return UTC with microseconds and zone info aware (because my database doesn't support zoneinfo)

```
    @property
    def UTC (self): 
        utc = self._UTC
        us  = self._uS
        # add microseconds
        utc += timedelta(microseconds=us)
        return utc.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    @UTC.setter
    def UTC (self,utc):
        self._UTC = utc-timedelta(microseconds=utc.microsecond) # without microseconds
        self._uS = utc.microsecond
```

Comment: Nice. I'll give this a try. Django 1.8 will have support for fractions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#database-backends

Comment: Please be aware the @property field won't work for filtering queries (MyModel.objects.filter(UTC...).For that use it is necessary to filter by _UTC and/or _uS separately